# ServiceStack LoadSelect throws ArgumentNull when child reference is null

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have a data model where child references of an object may be null (i.e. a secondary address may not be set on an account).  When I attempt to `LoadSelect` on the parent entity, I receive an `ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.` error, ostensibly when the child references are being loaded.

Given how common this data scenario is, am I just doing something wrong?  Else, is this a defect in `LoadListWithReferences`?

I've created a small sample program to illustrate this behavior:

```
using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;
using ServiceStack.OrmLite;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;


namespace SSLoadSelectTest
{
    public class Parent
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [References(typeof(Child))]
        public int? ChildId { get; set; }

        [Reference]
        public Child Child { get; set; }
    }

    public class Child
    {
        [PrimaryKey]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            OrmLiteConfig.DialectProvider = SqliteDialect.Provider;

            IDbConnection Db = SqliteDialect.Provider.CreateConnection(":memory:", new Dictionary<string, string>());
            Db.Open();

            Db.CreateTables(true, typeof(Parent), typeof(Child));

            Db.Insert<Child>(new Child() { Id = 1, Value = "Hello" });
            Db.Insert<Parent>(new Parent() { Id = 1, ChildId = (int)Db.LastInsertId() });
            Db.Insert<Parent>(new Parent() { Id = 2, ChildId = null });

            var results1 = Db.LoadSelect<Parent>(p => p.Id == 1);
            var results2 = Db.LoadSelect<Parent>(p => p.Id == 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has now [been fixed with this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/commit/c43b4c78d60633fde9b1e6b00640bfe8751ec25d).

This fix is available from **v4.0.32+** that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).